# Topojson coastal provinces

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

is there an "easy" way to tell if a country/province in a topojson map has a coast? Something like topojson.neighbors(), but that tells you if that province has a border not in common with anyone else.
I was thinking to join the map with a map of all the seas and check if they are neighbors, but I would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: This is a difficult task - if the sea layer doesn't have the same base data as its source (same scaling/simplification/datum/source/horizontal accuracy/etc), the topology won't align for any border and topojson.neighbors() will always be empty. You can account for this, but it would require some hand tweaking for different data sets. Also, depending on scale, loading very detailed world coast data may be inefficient. Are you dynamically loading lots of regions? If not, it is likely easier to hard code in each feature's properties if it is coastal or not.

Comment: I know, that's why I would like to find a different approach. Yes, I have a many regions, like 3000. I started from natural earth 110m with provinces and merged some

Comment: I'm sorry I mean 10m